# One connection per startup on network adapter on a system running Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, dell-inspiron

I have a Windows 7 64-bit, Dell Inspiron N5110 laptop with Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6230 wireless network adapter.

On startup the computer connects to my wireless network just fine, but when I try to disconnect and then reconnect to any network then the WiFi icon gets stuck. Renewal of IP via cmd doesn't work. Disabling the adapter works but enabling it again fails.

After Googling this problem I was suggested to restart the WLAN AutoConfig service.

When I tried doing so while this problem occurs the service wouldn't stop and the whole process got stuck.

The weird thing is that in safe mode with networking this problem disappears. I have already tried re-installing the network adapter driver.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Have you tried using a different version of the drive.  The device you have has reliability problems.  You might consider using a USB wireless adapter instead and disable the internal device.